# Domain name only works with www. but not without the www

Tags: dns, no-www, www

I have searched for this problem numerous times but I can't quite apply the solution to my problem. The usual solution I find is that I need to add an A-record to my dns, currently I only have a C-name record for host 'www' to my DNS.

The problem is, I'm having trouble understanding what goes in the 'host' section of the record when trying to create an A-record. Here is a screenshot to my domain registrar where I am trying to create the record.

[image]

I have tried creating an A-record with the 'host' field set to *, but that is not a valid entry, nor is leaving it blank.

Answer (score 2):

> I have tried creating an A-record with the 'host' field set to *, but that is not a valid entry, nor is leaving it blank.

An `A` record points directly to the *IP address* of your server.

However, this might be a restriction with your host (Amazon AWS?) since your site might not be served from any one server, so there is no one IP address that you can point to. In which case you could perhaps use a service such as wwwizer.com that provides the one IP address and performs the redirect for you.

Just to note, your site should only be accessible from one or the other (www or none-www), not both. It should redirect from one to the other - which is what you would need to do if you setup an `A` record.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I am using AWS and Godaddy, so I updated my `www` CNAME to `xxx.aws.amazon.com` and deleted the `A` record. After that I used a forwarding `301` (permanent redirect) and pointed it to `www.mysite.com`.

So in short use forwarding and point it to `www.yoursite.com`

Comment: Ok, but when people first visit mysite.com without the www, aren't 
they're just going to get an empty page?

Answer (score -1):

my domain registration is at hostway but my website is at squarespace. In managing the DNS I put a `CNAME` record for just my domain without the `www` under the source and put the website as the destination with a TTL of 14400 so it looks like this:

```
14400 example.com my-squarespace.example
```

no `@` or `www` for the host just the domain name.

Now when I go to `example.com` or `www.example.com` it goes to `https:www.example.com`

Comment: Using a CNAME at the domain root (apex) is not allowed by DNS spec.   Even though some DNS servers will let you do so, it may not work for all client.  It has unexpected side effects such as causing your MX to be ignored and email to that domain will stop working.